# Which relay will last the longest?

Tags: ac, relay, contactor, resistive-load

I'd like to control a 20 amp, 240 volt AC resistive load with a heavy duty contactor.

The contactor I have is a Siemens 3TX7130-0DB03 rated for 30 amps, and DPDT.  I was originally going to switch both lines on this relay.  But I got to thinking...

Would it be easier on the contactor to use both poles in parallel to switch the same line, and leave the other line always powered?
What theory or research would support that conclusion?

In short...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuqs2F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which of the above relays will last longer, why, and what other pros and cons are there?

Comment: If this is only for such low AC amperage and you are worried about wear, you may want to do what I did for a 240 VAC, 40 A situation. Turn on a solid state switch and the relay. The solid state switch turns on right away, while the relay takes its sweet time. Once the relay is engaged, heat dissipation in the solid state relay disappears. But the relay doesn't experience high voltage at moment of switching contact either. The carbon and wear on my relay contacts is pretty much entirely absent, now. They look "new" and the idea does work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question.

In terms of switching there is no real difference. When switching a contactor/relay one contact will always make or break first/last. Or to put it another way, only one contact actually does the switching. That is why you should never double up contacts to try to turn 30A relay into a 60A unit.

So, what else is there?

Contact resistance. When closed the circuit on the right shares the load current equally through both contacts and will therefor drop half the voltage and heat less. In the left circuit, both contacts must carry the full load so you end up with twice the voltage drop compared to a single contact.

There is one more factor. Isolation. In the left circuit when the contactor is off you have full isolation between the load and the supply. The right circuit you have only disconnected one line. The left circuit is therefore safer.

So in other words it comes down to do you prefer isolation versus quarter the voltage drop and a cooler contactor.

**ADDITION:**

Since folks brought it up in the comments, here are the fault scenarios, not including coil failure.

[image]

From this it is evident the series connection is possibly better if you need it to fail off.

Comment: My actual application is much more complicated than I had time to sketch up, and more than would have been relevant for the question of relay usage.  There exist several redundant safety mechanisms for isolation, so I didn't intend this relay to serve as safety isolation, and will happily take the cooler, more efficient contactor.  Even though I doubt the money I save will make up for the difference in parts cost between the DPDT and SPST models.

Comment: Also, the left circuit is more fail-safe. There a failing relay may result in an always-off state (a relay stuck in off-state), but never an always-on state. A relay fail on the right may prevent you turning the system off if a relay is stuck turned on. (IOW, the left circuit is AND, the right is OR-logic controlled.)

Comment: @Neinstein: However, if one contactor gets stuck on in the left circuit, the failure will be hidden, i.e. the circuit will continue to operate normally. If the other contactor later fails the same way, you can still get an always-on state. This may still be a less likely failure mode for the left circuit than for the right one, since it requires both contactors to fail successively in the same way, but saying that it cannot happen seems too strong a claim.

Comment: @BillyC. note update